# Rotation slowing down at the end

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

Im using GreenSock > TweenMax.to
So the title says it all.... I have this MC( with that name of **rays** ) that is slowing down when the function is nearly over

this is the code

`TweenMax.to(rays, 20, {rotation:"360", repeat:-1 });`

Why is this happening ? what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is likely because the default "easing function" is an "ease out" where the effect slows down at the end.

There are many easing functions to choose from, browse through them in this [visualizer](http://www.greensock.com/roughease/).

To override the easing function when calling `TweenMax.to()`, the [documentation](http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/TweenMax.html#to%28%29) says you need to specify a value for the `ease` option. You probably want the `Linear.easeNone` function that will play the effect at a consistent rate.

After importing the `Linear` class, you should be able to do this:

```
TweenMax.to(rays, 20, {rotation:"360", repeat:-1, ease: Linear.easeNone });
```

Comment: Hah I noticed the easing option, but did think that the default was set at None.Thanks

Comment: Grrr. I can't believe they'd do that. Thanks for the tip!